# SWIFT - How to make video background transparent while saving the video?

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, video-processing, video-player

Hi I want to save a video which I have made from editing a video - like adding filter and sticker and then retreiving all the frames as snapshots and making the photos merge into a video. My snapshots have clear background color. But when the video is saved, the background color of the saved video becomes BLACK instead of CLEAR/TRANSPARENT.

I have looked around for a while but could not find any solution. It will be a great help if someone could guide me a way around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using `AVAssetExportSession`, some presets support transparency including `AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQualityWithAlpha` (iOS 13 and above)